# How to create NPM, Javascript Project in VS2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, npm

I always see in tutorials, that they have a "special npm reference", which I have not.

[image]

All what I can see is the "normal" references (.net assemblys). I also do not find any pure "Javascript" Project type.

I am on Update 3. Do I need something special to make this work?

I have a package.json and Gulpfile.js in my project and compile LESS with it successfully, but don't see this references.

Comment: Do you have [Node.js Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/) installed? I believe that's where the JavaScript project types come from.

Comment: No, thank you @JoeClay, this looks promising

Comment: No problem! I'll post that as an answer too - if it ends up fixing your issue, could you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPM integration/JavaScript project type isn't included in the base install of Visual Studio. For these features to be available, you'll need the [Node.js Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/) extension - if I recall correctly, there's a shortcut to do this in the New Project wizard in recent versions of VS.